# Do the following two CFGs describe the same language

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Do the following two CFGs describe the same language

1. S → aS | bS | ε
2. S → aS | Sb | ε

Would the answer to this be no, because the order can't be switched? bS and Sb are different. I'm a bit confused about how I would find out if they described the same language.

Comment: In order to show that two grammars don't generate the same language, you have to find a word generated by one of the grammars but not by the other one.

Answer (score 1):

No. The word "abab" is described by (1) but not (2). You can test and visualize this [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1156/tools/cfg/).

Trying to think about it inductively: (1) can only prepend "a" or "b" to a string while (2) can only prepend "a" and only append "b".

Switching the order of a production does not necessarily change the language the grammar represents, but it is in this case. As to the second part of your question, [there is no generalizable or efficient way to determine whether two CFGs describe the same language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231187/an-efficient-way-to-determine-if-two-context-free-grammars-are-equivalent).